# Bottleneck on Heroku SSL according to Blitz.io

Tags: heroku

I have a simple Django app set up that I have been testing with Blitz.io.
When I test with many dynos I can get thousands of req/s on http:// X.com
When I switch to https:// X.com I get no more than 72 req/s no matter how many dynos.
And on https:// X.herokuapp.com/ I get more, but it still tops out at a few hundred req/s.

Is this a fluke that won't show up with normal use cases?  A Blitz issue?  A heroku issue?  Would resources just be scaled up with demand?

Comment: I am seeing very similar behaviour testing a Heroku app (node.js in my case) with Blitz.io over HTTPS. I've requested some clarification from Blitz.io at the bottom of this thread: http://support.blitz.io/discussions/questions/259-reconciling-differences-with-ssl-timeouts

Answer (score 2):

We had a very similar issue with blitz.io and loader.io. See our blog post at http://making.fiftythree.com/load-testing-an-unexpected-journey/ for more details. It's very possible that blitz.io is the cause of your issue with SSL. We found that [BlazeMeter](http://blazemeter.com/) could handle the load quite well.

If cost is a concern you might also want to try open source tools like [siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) or [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

**This answer assumes https://X.com uses the SSL:endpoint heroku addon to serve a custom cert.**

The ssl:endpoint addon is implemented using an AWS Elastic Load Balancer.  ELBs distribute load amongst their nodes using DNS. In my experience, each individual ELB node isn't particularly beefy, and SSL negotiation/decryption is non-trivial from a CPU perspective.  So it's important when load testing to:

1. Re-resolve the hostname with each request to distribute load amongst all the ELB ips, especially as new ones are added in response to increased traffic.
2. Ramp up your load test very slowly. Amazon advises to increase load on ELBs at most by 50% every 5 minutes.

I'm not particularly suprised if the difference between HTTP/HTTPS capacity in terms of concurrent connections allowed on a single ELB node is substantial, which if you're pinned to one IP, may account for the difference you're observing.

I don't know the details of the https://*.herokuapp.com stack, but I'm not surprised at all that it can service quite a bit more https traffic than a cold ssl:endpoint ELB.